# Apache Tika : Not able to extract embedded object from RTF file with {\*\objclass Outlook.FileAttach}

Tags: rtf, apache-tika

I have rtf file having embedded excelsheet. I am able to open the RTF file in MSword and can open the embedded excelsheet.
I am trying the extract the embedded excelsheet using Apache Tika but apache tika is not able to identify the type of file hence creating extracting the embedded object with ".unknown" extension.

In the RTF file the embedded object is appearing as

{{\object\objemb{*\objclass Outlook.FileAttach}\objw1440\objh1215{*\objdata

Since objclass is "Outlook.FileAttach" Apache Tika not able to identify the kind of embedded object.

Need help in identifying type of embedded object and how it can be extracted.

I have already tried to rename to ".unknown" file to ".msg", ".xls", ".xlsx" but did not work

Comment: If you ask Apache Tika to detect the type of the extracted file, what does it report?

Comment: It could not detect the type hence returned default one x-tika-msoffice

Comment: Can you run the Apache POI util `org.apache.poi.poifs.POIFSLister` (from the POI jar that comes with Tika) and edit your question with the entries it finds in the extracted file?